# Secure Connection between Windows Phone and Azure

Tags: c#, security, azure, azure-sql-database, secure-coding

I developed an social idea. Such as whatsapp, instagram or similar mobile applications. Decide to release first versions on Windows Phone. Of course, the best cloud choice will be Azure. I trust Microsoft and its products.

So, the question is "how can I keep my mobile app in secure (secure code advice, anti-decompiler?, encrypt source code, classes and files?) and get secured azure connection of the app?"

What does Microsoft or Azure offer to us? Privacy and security are my first goals for now.

Comment: Secure against what?  Eavesdropping? Copying your code?

Comment: Secure source codes, resources, Azure connection (i.e. connection strings, tokens etc.). I am open for every advice for security of mobile app

Comment: That's not really answering my question. The (C#) source does not need protection, neither do binaries on the server. Your mobile code is not really protectable.

Comment: Imagine that, you write an instagram app. how do you get measures for protecting your data and app?

Comment: How are all of your concerns at the moment designed right now (i.e. who has access to connection strings, what protocol are you using to connect to Azure, tokens, etc.? What privileges have you given to users to your database (if you have one); how is your app designed when you query the database (again if you have one)?

Comment: Security questions isn't about how to encrypt the source code, but more about how safe is the data your clients are consuming/creating/sharing. For example, what protocol you are using, protection against eavesdropping, how are you encrypting your data, who has **direct** access to connection strings, what privileges you are giving to your clients, etc.